# Implementing Kerberos and LDAP in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, kerberos, python-ldap

firstly, i'm very new to Django.

I have developed a Django app that includes a ticket system. Users should only see their own tickets. Now this self service system should be connected to the Microsoft account to enable a single sign on. To do this, the Django app must first be connected to Kerberos and then authenticated using LDAP. However, after extensive searching I cannot find any comprehensible documentation that explains the procedure. That's why I'm turning to you with the hope that someone can help me.

Many thanks in advance

Pablo

I tried using the Dkango Documentation and various other "Docs" which were either outdated or incomplete(like the official django documentation) also other helpful threads in here are outdated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.